# Determining Open Sets From Continuous Functions

Tags: general-topology

I don't understand the following logic:

If $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a function from a topological space $X$ to a topological space $Y$, and $f^{-1}(U)$ is an open set of $X$, where $U \subset Y$, and $f$ is continuous, then $U$ is an open set of $Y$.

Usually, how it proceeds is that we are first given that $f$ is continuous, then that $U \subset Y$ is an open set, and we conclude that $f^{-1}(U)$ is an open set of $X$. But we are doing the logic backwards here, and I don't understand how we can conclude that $U$ is an open set of $Y$.

Would somebody be able to explain how we reach this conclusion?

Thanks.

Comment: We need further conditions. For example that $f$ is a quotient map. Generally, consider a constant function to see that $f^{-1}(U)$ can be open without $U$ having to be open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This phenomenon that we "test" openness in $Y$ by looking at the inverse image in $X$ happens exactly when $f$ is a quotient map, or alternatively put, that $Y$ has the quotient (or "final") topology w.r.t. $f$. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)) or any good topology text book. So it is a special circumstance.

Comment: Yes, good point. I forgot to mention that $Y$ was given the final topology. Thank you, I understand :)